# App_Data folder is not checked in with Team Foundation Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, tfs, entity-framework-migrations

I use Team Foundation Server in Visual Studio 2015 to develop with Asp.Net Mvc 5. I usually use 2 computers and TFS is good friend to me. But I don't understand the simple problem, there isn't upload the folder `App_Data` when I check in project solution. This is problem to me, because I don't want to try change manually database changes again and again every day in second computer.

Anyone help me for quick solution?

Comment: Are you using Git or TFS's own version control? Do you have that folder ignored by your repository settings?

Comment: I am using TFS's own version control. No, I didn't ignore the folder.